# Sonarqube 7.8 Docker Image not able run after changing from jdk8 to jdk11

Tags: java, docker, sonarqube

I am upgrading my Sonarqube server from 6.7 to 7.8-community since the latest version can run on openjdk 11. The docker image Sonarqube has hosted is running on openjdk 8. I am trying to make the image run on a custom openjdk 11 version java-11-openjdk-11.0.3.7-0.0.1.el7_6.x86_64.

```
FROM sonarqube:7.8-community

COPY plugins /opt/sonarqube/extensions/plugins
COPY openjdk-11.0.3.tar.gz .

USER root

RUN \
tar -xvzf openjdk-11.0.3.tar.gz -C /usr/local && \ 
rm -rf openjdk-11.0.3.tar.gz 

ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/local/java-11-openjdk-11
```

The docker image fails to start with the error below.

```
2019.06.21 18:20:46 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up and running
2019.06.21 18:20:46 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] no modules loaded
2019.06.21 18:20:46 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty4Plugin]
2019.06.21 18:20:48 WARN  app[][o.s.a.p.AbstractManagedProcess] Process exited with exit value [es]: 1
2019.06.21 18:20:48 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[es] is stopped
2019.06.21 18:20:48 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped
```

Is there a better way of switching the java version?

Also how do we restart Sonarqube server from inside the docker container?

Comment: Restarting SonarQube is depending on how it is used/installed. You can run it as a service or start it using a batch file. Did you investigate all the SonarQube log files?

Comment: On exec on to the sonaqube image, under bin, I only see the run.sh. This file does not have a restart input.

Comment: Does [this](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/setup/operate-server/) documentation page help?

Comment: The documentation does not mention anything for docker container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was with the java home not added to path. I modified the Dockefile as below and it started working.

```
FROM sonarqube:7.8-community

COPY plugins /opt/sonarqube/extensions/plugins
COPY openjdk-11.0.3.tar.gz .

USER root

RUN \
tar -xvzf openjdk-11.0.3.tar.gz -C /usr/local && \ 
rm -rf openjdk-11.0.3.tar.gz 

ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/local/java-11-openjdk-11
ENV PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:${PATH}"
```